# Boot sequence of JBoss and Oracle

Tags: oracle, redhat, boot, jboss

G'day,

the recommended SysV startup files for JBoss and Oracle appear to have the wrong sequence.
For jboss the community recommends putting

`# chkconfig: 345 80 20`

into the /etc/init.d/jboss startup script, allowing chkconfig to create links S80jboss into the apropriate runlevels. The recommended Oracle (10g) script dbora however, contains

`# chkconfig: 345 99 10`

so, Oracle will be started *after* jboss, which is not what I would have expected.

What would a reasonable sequence be for Oracle and JBoss?

Stefan

Answer (score 2):

The suggested values are little more than guesses. Your best bet is to look at the values you have in your existing boot sequence and decide where you want Oracle and JBoss to fit in. e.g. start Oracle after the default OS stuff, and JBoss last.